# subprocess.popen not returning any output in cronjob

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

I have a python script which needs to gather output of a command line utility in linux. I had used below subprocess method to read output:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cmd","arg"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(raw_domain, err) = proc.communicate()
```

When I am executing the script manually from bash, it is working absolutely fine and returning the command output, however when I am adding this script execution to crontab, subprocess.popen is not returning any output.

Crontab expression:

```
* * * * root python /apoorv/cleanup_null_domain.py
```

I verified the 'blank' return using logs, and I am pretty sure about it.

Wanted to mention that, I had used os.popen method as well. Same results :(

Comment: Try to specify full path to your application (For example: use "/usr/bin/more" instead of "more"). Because user bash environment is not loading by default in cron process.

Comment: Define "not returning any output". You've captured stdout in `raw_domain` and stderr in `err`, so unless you print them they won't show up in any logs. Problem as it stands is unanswerable so better provide real code then a few handwavy boilerplate lines.

Comment: You are not capturing stderr (you need `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` in the Popen call) and you are not checking a return code. Use the return code to log errors to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're capturing stdout and stderr in your code, so it obviously isn't going to output anything. Either print the values, or better yet, write them to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your script an put in the first line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And make it executable

```
chmod +x /apoorv/cleanup_null_domain.py
```

Then in the crontab

```
* * * * root /apoorv/cleanup_null_domain.py
```

Comment: I ran across a few edits you made recently where you added "thanks in advance" to the end of questions. Please don't do that. Things like that should be _removed_ not added. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/318307) for more. Cheers

Comment: Ok, now how should I edit only code (formatting code) if the rules doesn´t allow to add only code, and some text is needed??? What can I do?

Comment: Great question. For [this one](/review/suggested-edits/17595113), removing the "Please HELP!" would have been enough. There are often other small things that can be fixed, if you read very carefully. [Look at revision 2 here](/posts/46713377/revisions), which is what another user did after rejecting your edit. For the situations where there really is nothing else to change, consider if the edit is really necessary. If it is, either leave a comment or ask someone in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) to edit it. When you get to 2000 rep, there isn't a limit on edit length.

Comment: Thanks. I´ll take it into account.